# Logo not showing up on ActionBar

Tags: android

Hello everyone on the Android Documentation it tells me to create a new file under res/menu and add the logo through there. I have done that as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:title="GoodString"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

But when I run my app the logo does not show up on my app's ActionBar. Is there some sort of connection I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you add menu in the code?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: here is the guide link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have this as well

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yourFolderMenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu itself should be added under res/menu, while the icon/images go under the res/drawable folder. So you should put the menu(xml) file under res/menu and the logo under res/drawable(based on different resolution) folder

Comment: That's what I currently have.